# How to create post comparison in wordpress

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, theme-development, javascript

I am creating a feature in the child theme which is vehicles(car) comparison. the checkbox will add the vehicles(car) in the compare list from the car listing page. and compare page will give the compression of the selected vehicles(car). I want to create this flow, how can I create this. I have created vehicles custom post type.

Comment: "how can I create this" is a bit too generic to receive an useful response I guess. Maybe you could try to add a bit more details about what you want to do and what are your bloking issue. Just try to not make the question too specific for your context, since it should remains useful for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just gather all the car's id into one array and pass it to compare page and fetch only those cars which have ids in compare car array.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).